# update particular field in .net core by ef with repository and unit of work

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have repository,service and unit of work.

I have user model in which username,password,gender and multiple record is available.

I am access all data of user controller's model in an method then i want to update only password from whole data.

So how can we do this?

Comment: Provide more information on what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show some implentation that you have tried:

In your `RepositoryBase`, or equivalent, you can add something like:

```
            entityToUpdate.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            Context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            //Beware of tracked queries
            Context.SaveChanges();
```